# Attempted import error: 'match-sorter' does not contain a default export (imported as 'matchSorter')?

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lig7U.png)

a.Attempted import error: 'match-sorter' does not contain a default export (imported as 'matchSorter').
b.ERROR in ./node_modules/crypto-extra/dist/encryption.js 11:31-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'G:\react\tmth\node_modules\crypto-extra\dist'
c.BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.